# How to prove this property of absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone please help me on how to prove this property for absolute values:

$|a-b|\ge||a|-|b||$

Comment: Since all is non negative you can square

Comment: Step 1: Use the standard triangle inequality to show that $|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$. Step 2: Use the fact that $|a-b|=|b-a|$. Step 3: Put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|a-b|+|b|\ge |(a-b)+b|=|a|$ $\implies$ $|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|$

$|a|+|b-a|\ge|a+(b-a)|=|b|$ $\implies$ $|a|-|b|\ge -|a-b|$

$|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|\ge-|a-b|$ $\implies$ $|a-b|\ge||a|-|b||$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$|a-b|\cdot |a+b|=||a|-|b||\cdot ||a|+|b|| \Rightarrow |a-b|\ge ||a|-|b||,$$
because:
$$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|=||a|+|b||.$$